# A random output images

Tags: java, swing

Welcome) have a little trouble, help solve them, please. Here's the code:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

class MyCanvas extends JComponent {

  public void paint(Graphics g) {
    Image img1 = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("yourFile.gif");

    int width = img1.getWidth(this);
    int height = img1.getHeight(this);

    int scale = 2;
    int w = scale * width;
    int h = scale * height;
    // explicitly specify width (w) and height (h)
    g.drawImage(img1, 10, 10, (int) w, (int) h, this);

  }
}

public class Graphics2DDrawScaleImage {
  public static void main(String[] a) {
    JFrame window = new JFrame();
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setBounds(30, 30, 300, 300);
    window.getContentPane().add(new MyCanvas());
    window.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

If we run the code, we have displayed a picture.But my task is to bring many of the same image but in different places. How to do it?)

If you do so:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 500 ; i+=100){
g.drawImage(img1, 10+i, 10, (int) w, (int) h, this);
}
```

Then the images are displayed in a row. And I would like more randoml

Comment: have a look here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html

Comment: Thank you all! The main thing that pictures do not "jump"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> And I would like more random

Use the `Random` class to generate an integer within your specified range. You would want to use `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` to get the bounds of your component so you can specify a realistic range. Then you can randomize the x, y values.

```
Random random = new Random();
int x = random(getWidth());
int y = random(getHeight();
```

You might also want to consider the width/height of your images to make sure they are fully contained in the panel.

Also, custom painting is done by overriding the `paintComponent(...)` method not the paint() method.

Comment: Generally we would like to make the pictures were not only in the panel but also outside it to me for a little game.I want to scatter a variety of objects (pictures) on the map

Answer (score 1):

You are indeed correct that you can draw the same image multiple times by calling

```
g.drawImage(img1, x, y, (int) w, (int) h, this);
```

multiple times for different values of x and y. So, basically what you need to do is randomizing the coordinates. That can be done by using the handy `Random` class in Java:

```
Random random = new Random();
int x = random.nextInt(300);
int y = random.nextInt(300);
```

This will generate random coordinates between (0, 0) and (299, 299).

Answer (score 1):

You can use Random:

```
Random rand = new Random();

for(int i = 0; i < 500 ; i+=100){
    g.drawImage(img1, rand.nextInt(300), rand.nextInt(300), (int) w, (int) h, this);
}
```